# how to convert colums to rows in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a table with the following values

[image]

and I need the output values as below.

[image]

Please help to arrive the code

Comment: Don't tag products not involved. Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not pretty, but this would work:

```
select *
from
(
select nams_contract_number, 1 as Sequence, 'Preqc' as DataType, act_preqc, est_preqc
from table
union all
select nams_contract_number, 2 as Sequence, 'abstractoin' as DataType, act_abstraction, est_abstraction
from table
union all
select nams_contract_number, 3 as Sequence, 'review' as DataType, act_review, est_review
from table
union all
select nams_contract_number, 4 as Sequence, 'postreview' as DataType, act_postreview, est_postreview
from table
) x
order by x.nams_contract_number, x.sequence
```